# binary response variable and categorical predictors in phylolm package

Tags: r, binary-data, summary, phylogeny

I am using phylolm package to run a model with binary response variable (0/1), and a continuous predictor and a categorical predictor having more than 3 levels. If I consider the categorical predictor as continuous, i.e., 0, 1, 2, 3, the model ran well and I can use summary(model) to obtain the model output. However, this kind of treatment (treating categorical levels as continuous) does not fit the reality, I think it will be right to consider them as category, in this way, The model worked, but I had the problem to obtain the model output, as when I used summary(model), it gave the results for each category compared to the first. I would like to have an "anova" kind of table to summarize the significance of each variable, however, anova function does not apply to this kind of analysis. I want to ask is there any way to obtain the results for this model?

Some example scripts:

```
require(phylolm)

set.seed(123456)
# Simulate a tree of 50 species
tre = rtree(50)
# Simulate a continuous trait
conTrait = rTrait(n=1,phy=tre)
# Make a design matrix for the binary trait simulation
X = cbind(rep(1,50),conTrait)
# Simulate a binary trait
binTrait = rbinTrait(n=1,phy=tre, beta=c(-1,0.5), alpha=1 ,X=X)
# Simulate a radom categorical trait
catTrait <- 
as.factor(sample(c("A","B","C"),size=length(tre$tip.label),replace=TRUE))
# Create data frame
dat = data.frame(binTrait = binTrait, conTrait = conTrait, catTrait = catTrait)
### run the model
fit = phyloglm(binTrait ~ conTrait*catTrait, phy=tre, data=dat)

##model output
summary(fit)

Call:
phyloglm(formula = binTrait ~ conTrait * catTrait, data = dat, 
    phy = tre)
   AIC     logLik Pen.logLik 
 52.07     -19.04     -17.28 

Method: logistic_MPLE
Mean tip height: 3.596271
Parameter estimate(s):
alpha: 1.437638 

Coefficients:
               Estimate   StdErr z.value p.value
(Intercept)        -0.61804  0.83270 -0.7422  0.4580
conTrait            1.52295  1.16256  1.3100  0.1902
catTraitB           0.92563  0.98812  0.9368  0.3489
catTraitC          -0.24900  1.01255 -0.2459  0.8057
conTrait:catTraitB  0.49031  1.41858  0.3456  0.7296
conTrait:catTraitC -0.74376  1.29850 -0.5728  0.5668

Note: Wald-type p-values for coefficients, conditional on alpha=1.437638
```